# Remove whitespace from filteting url django tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a few urls that I am using for filtering. When I look for values using the specific urls I get

1. `api/v1/labels/?brand_city__location__state_or_country=New%20York`
2. `api/v1/labels/?brand_city__city=Novi%20Sad`

Alot of values being used will have a space inbetween words. How can I remove `%20` from the spaces and have the url be cleaner to return:

Desired: `api/v1/labels/?brand_city__city=Novi Sad` no `%20` present

**api.py**

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:

        filtering =  {
            "state_or_country": ALL
        }

class CityResource(ModelResource):

    location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'location', full=True)

    class Meta:

        filtering =  {
            "city": ALL,
            "location": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

class LabelResource(ModelResource):

    brand_city = fields.ForeignKey(CityResource, 'brand_city', full=True)

    class Meta:

        filtering = {
           "brand_category": ALL,
           "brand_city": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

**snippet response**

```
{
  "labels": [
    {
      "brand_city": {
        "city": "Manhattan",
        "location": {
          "location_choices": "State",
          "state_or_country": "New York"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "limit": 6,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the python function [urllib2.unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote)

```
# you can convert your urls using urlib2 library
path = urllib2.unquote("api/v1/labels/?brand_city__location__state_or_country=New%20York")
```

Also, like `unquote`, another function `unquote_plus` can also be used which also replaces plus signs by spaces, as required for unquoting HTML form values. Use according to your requirement